# What does this piece of Javascript (JQuery) do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, encryption

I have the following piece of code:

```
ts.decrypt({
        data: new ts.Buffer(atob(t), "hex"),
        key: new ts.Buffer("3VNWPhvh4yZH50WgWVJBQv9ii7z8FL7N"),
        progress_hook: function () {
        }
    }, function (t, n) {
        t || (e = n.toString(), ts.encrypt({
            data: new ts.Buffer(String.fromCharCode(123, 34) + 'p":"' + $("#password").val() + '"' + xobby(atob("bREPXDBWNSFfEFEZYwJVAlArJQRxfQ=="), "A3i3B5Pm0w8wA8wd1GVaS")),
            key: new ts.Buffer(e),
            progress_hook: function () {
            }
        }, function (e, t) {

            if (!e) {
                var n = t.toString("hex");

                console.log(n);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: window.location.href,
                    data: {passwordObj: n},
                    success: function (e) {
                        $("#loading").hide(), alert(e), window.scroll(0, 0)
                    }, async: !1
                })

            }
        }))
    })
```

and I have to analyse what it does.
Now I already figured out that it takes the value from the password input-field, encrypts it and sends it to the server using ajax.

I'm secifically puzzled by what ts is (Its heavily obscured...everything above this code looks like compiled CoffeeScript) 
and what "t ||" means (for me thats an or-operator).

Any help with understanding this code is appreciated.

Comment: There's no way to tell from this what `ts` is.  That OR operator `t || ...` is basically "if NOT t, then do all that stuff afterwards."

Comment: I like how the code first does `t || ( ...` and immediately after `if (!e) { ...`

Comment: Doesn't look like compiled CoffeeScript to me, CoffeeScript would properly hoist the `var n` up to the top of the function.

Comment: thanks @Josiah, that cleared a couple of things up.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you just need basic js-knowledge to get to that website's secret http://websec.sec.in.tum.de/. 
The input-box is totally ignorable. 
`xobby(atob("bREPXDBWNSFfEFEZYwJVAlArJQRxfQ=="), "A3i3B5Pm0w8wA8wd1GVaS")` is interesting. What it does is creating the String `,"forceLogin":"false"}` which you want to change to `,"forceLogin":"true"}`. In your code...

```
data: {
      passwordObj: n
},`
```

..that `n` is then the secret. You can get it with console.log(n). 
Next you make a POST request to http://websec.sec.in.tum.de/ with key passwordObj and your secret.
(Greetz to pentz)

Answer (score -1):

This will give an error at

```
var n = t.toString("hex");
```

It has to be

```
var n = t.toString(16);
```

And this code is incomplete.

This is probably (I guess) a Node.js code, and not meant to be run as JavaScript.

What you say as "everything above this code" could be probably Asm.js
You will have to find the original source code in that case..

This could be a code written by someone at ElevateSoft.
Check this out.. http://www.elevatesoft.com/forums?action=view&category=edb&id=edb_general&page=14&msg=8843

Comment: You're assuming that `t` is a Number, but it could be something else.  Also, since it has jQuery in it, it's clearly meant to run on the client side.

Comment: FYI, JQuery CAN be run on the server side with NodeJS.

And what's up with the down-vote.? I just pointed out where it "could" go wrong.